# Lists and libraries are not showing in sp designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

I created on site and working with work flows. I created reusable work flow. Now I want to associate that workflow with shared documents library. Whe I open the shared documents library in sharepoint desginer it is showing below message.
[image]

I closed the designer and again open it and clicked on the **lists and libraries** in the left pane. In the middle pane it is showing `

> there are no items to show in this view.

I searched with similar type of questions in this site. But no one solve my problem. Thats why again asking it.
Can any one faced this situation?

`

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I found a way.

First, I knew a list was broken, based on symptoms reported from other posts.

I couldn't discover which list it was that was broken, so in SPD, I went to "All Files" which worked, even though many of the other Site Objects in "Navigation" didn't display anything.

I went through every list in "All Files" and used "Preview in Browser" on every one of them.  Finally, I came to one that didn't open!  Instead, it said,

> feature d57f48.... for list template '100' is not installed in this farm...

So I deleted that list and everything began working again just fine in SPD.

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things:

- Try refreshing the view (F5)
- Make sure the site is loading in the browser

Comment: Both are working perfectly... No issues with those two aspects..

Comment: Anything else?  I'm having this problem, too.